# Can i include linux executables in my android application?

Tags: python, android, linux, exe, 7zip

I have created a python app that calls subprocess to `7z.exe` On windows and `7z` on linux and it works fine.

```
subprocess.run('7z x ...')
```

What about android will the linux executable version of `7z`
work with my python script on android?

Comment: It will as long as the dependencies exist and it's the tight CPU architecture. Most Android devices nowadays use ARM64, but there may also be Intel x64 devices for instance, and possibly others...

Comment: Bear in mind that what you propose violates the terms of the Play Store distribution rules, and there may be other app distribution channels that have similar restrictions.

Comment: @CommonsWare Please elaborate, what is the violation, where can I find this in the Play Store distribution rules? Is it simply the inclusion of the Linux exe or the instructions?

Comment: @ShimonRothschild: I was thinking of https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9888379. However, that was rewritten at some point and makes it easier to support what is being proposed here, if everything is packaged into the app.

Comment: Thank you. What I understand is a Linux executable is ok, but is restricted but the same rules as native code. Seems an unnecessary cyber risk. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the CPU architecture of the phone.
The most common CPU processor types of android smartphones are arm, arm64, x86.

When you build linux binaries on your linux system (debian, ubuntu), you must consider, that there is neither a full standard C-libary e.g. [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), nor a faster smaller embedded libc like [dietlibc](https://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/) on android.

So you must compile a static binary with all libs linked in and maybe cross compile the binary with gcc for several most common android cpus.

Java vm abstraction is standard for android applications.
When you execute a linux binary from your android app like [SDMaid does it](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm&hl=de_AT&gl=US), please take care, that the binary will be located inside the app data partition (with all mount restrictions of that partition) and that it will be run under UserId and GroupId of that Android App. (UserId and GroupId will normally be different on any android phone, because they depends on the installation order of the specific app and how many apps where preinstalled from android phone vendor).